# Finding bounds for a double integral

Tags: integration

I have a problem asking me to solve this:

> $$I=\iint_D 4 dA$$
>   Where D is the region in the first quadrant bounded by the lines $y=2$ and $y=x$ and between the circles $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=8$.

How should I go about finding the bounds? Our teacher told us a hint to integrate with respect to θ first (after substituting the variables), but I'm not sure how to start doing that.

Comment: I can't even *see* the picture in the link.  Please type the formula using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By linearity $$I = 4 \iint_D dA = 4 \,\textrm{area}(D) ,$$ but $D$ is a right triangle with a sector of a circle removed, so we can compute the area using elementary geometry.

Alternative, if you want to integrate using polar coordinates, notice that the lower bound for $r$ is defined the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 4$, so $r^2 = 4$, or $r = 2$, and that the upper bound by the curve $y = 2$, so $r \sin \theta = 2$, or $r = 2 \csc \theta$.